# Облачная АТС Билайн - API не работают Xsi-Events

Tags: события, asterisk, облако, телефония

Не работают события по звонкам **Xsi-Events** в облачной АТС Билайна.

Подписываюсь на события:

```
PUT https://cloudpbx.beeline.ru/apis/portal/subscription

{
    "expires": 3600,
    "subscriptionType": "BASIC_CALL",
    "url": "https://example.ru/some/url"
}
```

Возвращается ответ 200 OK:

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "0d62739d-84ed-4198-884e-6c3f29dae147",
    "expires": 3600
}
```

Получаю информацию по созданной подписке:

```
GET https://cloudpbx.beeline.ru/apis/portal/subscription?subscriptionId=0d62739d-84ed-4198-884e-6c3f29dae147

{
    "subscriptionId": "0d62739d-84ed-4198-884e-6c3f29dae147",
    "targetType": "GROUP",
    "targetId": "MPBX_g_103210",
    "subscriptionType": "BASIC_CALL",
    "expires": 3591,
    "url": "https://example.ru/some/url"
}
```

Начинаю звонить, но ничего на переданный url не приходит. URL был корректный (не тот что в примере выше), я его проверил - запросы принимает. Также пробовал hookbin.com, requestb.in - тоже не приходят запросы. При этом подписка исчезает как только АТС билайна видит звонок. То есть, в ответ на:

```
https://cloudpbx.beeline.ru/apis/portal/subscription?subscriptionId=0d62739d-84ed-4198-884e-6c3f29dae147
```

Сразу начинает возвращаться:

```
{
    "errorCode": "GetSubscriptionInfoError",
    "description": "Не удалось получить информацию"
}
```

Повторял много раз - создал подписку, получаю информацию по ней GET https://cloudpbx.beeline.ru/apis/portal/subscription но как только приходит звонок - начинает возвращать ошибку, вместо данных о подписке.

Тех. поддержку Билайна по этому продукту найти не удается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для корректной работы событий от АТС, принимающий события сервер должен всегда возвращать 200-ый статус по HTTP (АТС не дружит с HTTPS и шлёт форсированно по HTTP), при любых других статусах АТС будет отзывать подписку.

Comment: Спасибо. Удалось связаться с поддержкой, действительно с https не дружит, пришлось переходить на http для запросов от Билайна.

Answer (score 2):

Решали такую же проблему. Техподдержка Билайна не могла решить вопрос в течение 1 месяца (!!!), решили копать сами. В итоге выяснили, что билайн обращался к нам не по адресу (который мы указывали в команде "Подписка на события"):

```
http://example.ru/test.php
```

а по адресу:

```
http://example.ru/test.php/null
```

Откуда они взяли null непонятно. После этого любые вопросы к техподдержке отпали. Сделали redirect на стороне nginx, и все заработало.